# Android - Split String by lines

Tags: android

I'm trying to save the data of 4 variables on the SharedPreferences and load it to a list. My problem is that it shows all the data in the first line of the list. I wanted to split like: Everytime I click the save button I wanted to save the 4 variables and when I click it again and I want to save the new variables and display it a new line.

Showing All on the same index: [image]

TubeDataFragment (save):

```
public class TubeDataFragment extends Fragment {

List<String> tubeData = new ArrayList<>();


public TubeDataFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tube_data, container, false);

    final Spinner spinnerMaterial = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.snipperMaterial);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.material));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerMaterial.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    //controls
    Button btn_saveTube = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_tube);
    final EditText et_diameter = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_diameter);
    final EditText et_clr = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_clr);
    final EditText et_thickness = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_thickness);

    //guarda dados do tubo
    btn_saveTube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tubeData.add(" Diameter: " + et_diameter.getText().toString());
            tubeData.add(" Thickness: " + et_thickness.getText().toString());
            tubeData.add(" CLR: " + et_clr.getText().toString());
            tubeData.add(" Material: " + spinnerMaterial.getSelectedItem().toString());

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 1;
            for(String data : tubeData)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(data);
                stringBuilder.append(";");

                if(i++ == tubeData.size())
                {
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }

            }
            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("tubeData", stringBuilder.toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

ArchiveFragment (load)

```
public class ArchiveFragment extends Fragment {


public ArchiveFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archive, container, false);

    ListView tubeDataList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tubeData_list);

    //load tube data
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
    String tubeDataString = settings.getString("tubeData", "");
    String[] tubeDataSplit = tubeDataString.split("\n");

    List<String> tubeDataItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<tubeDataSplit.length;i++)
    {
        tubeDataItems.add(tubeDataSplit[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tubeDataItems);


    // Assign adapter to ListView
    tubeDataList.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: If you want a list, then store a JSONArray as a string

Comment: what's the difference? this should work with a list...

Comment: The difference is its more optimal than using a string builder that you append to and later split from

Comment: You split on `\n` character, but I think you only have one due to your if condition: `i++ == tubeData.size()`. That will only evaluate to true the once (likely the last time the loop is executed).

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE you are correct. it only adds one \n in the end. I need to a \n something like every 4 data

Comment: @adiajdiadj; Then remove your if statement

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE that way it adds a \n in the end of each variable. it splits all. I want to split every 4

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE it's dirty but It works i++; if(i%4==0) \n

Comment: @adiajdiadj; The modulo operator is not really dirty. If you need to do something every n times, the modulo operator is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Your **if** condition is wrong.

**In `TubeDataFragment`, use below codes in `onClick()` method:**

```
    .............
    ..................
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 1;
    for(String data : tubeData)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(data);
        stringBuilder.append(";");

        if(i == 4)
        {
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    ...............
    .......................
```